# Are angular material and materila-ui and Materializecss related to material design?

Tags: css, angular-material, material-design, materialize

Are [angular material](https://material.angular.io/) and [material-ui](https://material-ui.com/) and [Materializecss](https://materializecss.com/) related to [material design](https://material.io/design)?

If you learn one does it make it easy to learn and apply the rest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are all related to the Material Design design language, which may help knowing what components you need for a given website, however; they all use very different technologies and programmer interfaces.

For instance, learning Material UI for React with its properties, events, styling method, etc. don't translate well into MaterializeCSS with it's completely different developer interface, but you may know that for a given project, you will need card components even if how you create them is different.

I'd you're looking for where to start to get into a Material styled framework, pick the one relating to the framework that closest matches your needs or your existing experiences.

Answer (score 0):

Lol. I just found out that they are. It is written in plain text on the respective websites.

angular material, on [their website](https://material.angular.io/), is described as:

> ***Material Design*** components for Angular.

material-ui, on [their website](https://material-ui.com/), is described as:

> React components for faster and easier web development. Build your own
> design system, or start with ***Material Design***.

Materializecss, on [their website](https://materializecss.com/), is described as:

> A modern responsive front-end framework based on ***Material Design***.

[material design](https://material.io/design), on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_Design) is described as:

> ***Material Design*** is a design language developed by Google in 2014.
> Expanding on the "cards" that debuted in Google Now, Material Design
> uses more grid-based layouts, responsive animations and transitions,
> padding, and depth effects such as lighting and shadows.